# Converting TimeSpan to milliseconds in linq query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to add a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` in a linq query using entity framework. I've got the following code:

**EDIT**

`TimeSlots`is an `ICollection<TimeSlot>`

`TimeSlot` has the properties `DateTime Start` and `TimeSpan Duration`

```
var linq = from s in schedulesBase
           join c in channelBase on s.ChannelId equals c.ChannelId
           select new
           {
                ...
                TimeSlots = s.TimeSlots,
                ...
           };

var timeslots = linq.SelectMany(t => t.TimeSlots);

return from s in timeslots
       select new Resources.Event
       {
            ...
            end = DbFunctions.AddSeconds((DateTime?)s.Start, (Int32?)s.Duration.Seconds)
            ...
       };
```

It compiles fine but doesn't add any time from `s.Duration.Seconds` to `end`.
Since the following code works

```
end = DbFunctions.AddSeconds((DateTime?)s.Start, 500)
```

and behaves as expected I must be doing something wrong with the conversion from `TimeSpan` to seconds.

What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: What is the type of `s.Duration`? Are you certain it's `Seconds` property is no 0?

Comment: s.Duration is of type TimeSpan

Comment: Where does `s` come from? Could you give us more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you're using `Seconds` instead of `TotalSeconds`. The `Seconds` property only gives a value in the range `[-59, 59]` - so 5 minutes and 30 seconds would return 30, not 330, for example.

Try:

```
end = DbFunctions.AddSeconds((DateTime?)s.Start, (Int32?)s.Duration.TotalSeconds)
```

Comment: Since this actually answers my question I've accepted the answer. However, by using `s.Duration.TotalSeconds` I get System.NotSupportedException during runtime. Additional information: The specified type member 'TotalSeconds' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Is there a work around to this problem?

Comment: @EmilKling: It's *possible* that `SqlFunctions.DatePart` will do what you want - it's hard to tell for sure. Just to check, is `timeslots` still an `IQueryable<>`? If you had `s` as a local variable, you could just extract the total seconds first...